# Entities are not supported: [NamedCredential] : sfdx package

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx

I created a `Managed` package with sfdx and then a version:

`sfdx:force:package2:version:create -d Folder`

and get this error:

> These entities are not supported: [NamedCredential]

If I create an `Unlocked` package it works perfectly. My project contains NamedCredential.

Any idea ?